# Example of non-local homomorphism on local rings

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism, local-rings

Could someone give an example for a homomorphism between local rings which is not local?

I tried finding the example by defining a homomorphism from Z/9Z to Z/3Z which maps a+9Z to a+3Z. But it turns out that 0,3,6(i.e. non units of Z/9Z) are mapped to 0(non unit in Z/3Z). Thus it isn't local homomorphisms.

I usually struggle to find examples on my own. Any suggestions, how to improve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about $R=\{a/b:a,b\in\Bbb Z, b\text{ odd}\}$ where the maximal ideal is $2R$
and $S=\Bbb Q$. Then the inclusion $R\to S$ is not a local homomorphism.